# Using XMLHttpRequest with PHP Session

Tags: javascript, php, session, xmlhttprequest, intel-xdk

I am developing a mobile app with html5 (Intel XDK) and coding server side with php. In my application users can upload image from mobile to server. But when I changed the server side code to check *is user logged in* with session, session variable returns null. My code is like below.

```
var par= new FormData(document.getElementById('form')); 
var obj= new XMLHttpRequest();
...
obj.open('POST', 'url.com/upload.php');
obj.send(par);
```

And in server side code I want to check session variable.

```
if($_SESSION['user_logged_in'] == 1)
```

I searched for this problem in SO but results have some problems. For example, In the post below, answer says that session id must keep in client side but I think It is not a good solution because of security problems.

> [How to pass php session with XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981010/how-to-pass-php-session-with-xmlhttprequest/6981114#6981114)

Is there any good iplementation for this problem?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am calling session_start and If I remove logged in check It works. Other pages that I called with Ajax reaches session variables. My doubts about security is that my session id will be seen in source code, won't it be a security problem?

Comment: Can you check (with fiddler, chrome tools etc) whether the session cookie is being sent with the request? And are you calling session_start() at the beginning of in upload.php?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to pass a session id. How do you think the browser works with session normally?

Comment: @johnnycardy yes I am calling session start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the App Security API Cordova plugin to improve the protection measures on your session token/id,
You can find more details on this Cordova plugin [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/app-security-api/api).
Also available for you are links to code snippets for 'Storing in Secure Storage' and 'Reading from Secure Storage' [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/604512).

By the way, the App Security API is supported in Intel XDK, you can add it to your application it by using the plugin management menu--> featured plugin--> App Security API --> click ‘add plugin’.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't keep the session id in client side, how you can be identified by the server ?
You can change session id with strong-generated one, it's the best approach.

And please, verify if cookies are enabled, etc etc.
So, you have to do some debugging.

Comment: I check my code, sessions are working on pages that I called with ajax post.